# Android. Why does not work layout gravity when I define ListView's height programmatically?

Tags: android, layout, gravity

If I define ListView's height in XML the layout gravity is working, but I want calculate the height programmatically, but in this case the layouts sliding over one another.

The XML:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:hint="Search..."
    android:background="@drawable/bar"
    android:inputType="text"
   android:layout_gravity="top" />

<ListView
     android:id="@+id/contactlist"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="400dp" 
     android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
```

**Code:**

```
TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
    {
       actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
Point size = new Point(); 
display.getSize(size); 
int layoutHeight = size.y - 59 - actionBarHeight;

listView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,layoutHeight));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
    LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = layoutHeight;
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
```